# welcome message -- display one time only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure if I can make you understand my problem. I have title.jsp included in all other jsps of the application, including the login page. After the login page the welcome message(is a 3d div) should  appear only 1 time. This I am trying to achieve through only from the client side. This works and the message does not show up on the login page

```
<c:if test="${null != sessionScope.loggedInUser}">
        <input type="hidden" value="here" id="messageTest">
</c:if>
```

this means if the logged user is null then this hidden element is not rendered and in javascript in document ready function I have this

```
if($("#messageTest").length !=0 ){

    if($("#messageTest").val() == "here"){

        alert("calling welcome function");  
        $("#messageTest").val("there");
        showWelcomeMessage();
    }
}
```

but now this message comes on every page....I understand why it is happening. But how can I make this jsp remember the value ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: cookies...session variable...URL changes...etc

Comment: @Deryck is right, you can use those to determine if the message has been displayed or not.

Comment: also can use the `referrer` URL to determine if they are just coming from the login page and if not, you hide the message

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I do with session variable?